# JavaScript Does Not Wait For Window to Load

Tags: javascript, webautomation

I am writing a code meant for a browser's console without libraries that types some textA from an array in a searchBar1, hits the searchButton1, waits for the window to load, types some textB in a searchBar2, hits the searchButton2, clicks a circle, then clicks a final button. When I run each of the lines of the code separately, manually waiting for each command to be processed, the code runs as it should. However, whenever I try to run the code all at once, all code placed after clicking the searchButton1 does not work.

The issue isn't that Preserve Logs isn't turned on - it is. I believe the problem is that JS simply isn't waiting for the window to load

I've tried using the load and DOMContentLoaded events on the window and document properties, tried using onload and await, and no luck in any case. I even tried using chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener, but, curiously enough, it didn't even run on the console. Here's the code below for reference:

```
//Declare CPFs Array
let cpfs = \\ List goes here 

// Declare text variable containing the msg you want the computer to send
let text = "visa"

//Declare search bar variable
let searchBar = document.querySelector("input.form-control:nth-child(1)")

//Declare search button variable
let searchButton = document.querySelector(".btn-primary")

//loops through CPFs Array
for (var i = 0; i < cpfs.length; i++) {

    //Types the client's name
    searchBar.value = cpfs[i]
    searchBar.dispatchEvent(
        new Event("input", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true })
    );

    //Clicks the search button
    searchButton.click()
    
    //Wait for window to load
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        //assign variable for the second search bar
        var inputBar = document.querySelector("input.form-control:nth-child(2)")

        //Sets value on the second search bar to the text you are looking for in the message to be sent 
        inputBar.value = text
        inputBar.dispatchEvent(
            new Event("input", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true })
        );

        //assign variable for the circle
        var circle = document.querySelector("html body.skin-blue.pg-login.sidebar-mini div#app.app.ng-scope div.wrapper.ng-scope div.content-wrapper section.content div.ng-scope div.row.ng-scope div.box.box-warning div.box-header div.col-md-12 div.box.box-default.box-solid div.box-body div.table-responsive div#envioNotificacoesTable_wrapper.dataTables_wrapper.form-inline.dt-bootstrap.no-footer div.row div.col-sm-12 table#envioNotificacoesTable.table.table-striped.envioNotificacoes.ng-isolate-scope.no-footer.dataTable tbody.ng-scope tr.ng-scope.odd td input.left-10")

        //click the circle
        circle.click()

        //Assigns variable for the button to send the message
        var sendButton = document.querySelector(".btn-success")

        //Sends the message
        sendButton.click()
    })

    //Wait for message to be sent
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    alert("Message sent!")  

    })
}
```

All help is welcome, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your script declared? Because it's very much possible that your script (with, say, `defer`) is already only executed after window load, which would mean you never get the load event again. I don't think it's a good idea to try to do stuff before load as you will never be guaranteed you can do that depending on the load itself? Either way, we need to know how you add your script to the page before we can draw conclusions.

Comment: If you put a useful value for `cpfs` in for us, consider changing your code to a runnable snippet (the `<>` button). Using DOMContentLoaded (see [MDN docs for DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event#basic_usage)) on the document should work, though. Do you get any errors on the browser console?

Comment: The script is declared on the browser's console. I'm not familiar with "defer", what is it? 

I doubt that the whole of the script is executed only once the window is loaded, given that it is the script that triggers the loading, but may be! How could I check that, somethinghere?

Comment: Does it matter what value "cpfs" has? If not, you can use any string to emulate it

Also, what is a runnable snippet? 

I tried using DOMContentLoaded before, sadly it didn't work. But thanks for the insight!

And no, I don't get any errors in the browser console

Comment: Why don't you uses JQuery or something similar to load the javascript after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Sadly I can't use libraries in this project. I should have specified that in the main post, sorry. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Take a look at [mre] for more about what's expected for runnable snippets. Also [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) from the [meta-tag:faq].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just making sure that I got it, should I provide the HTML, CSS and JS of the page I'm trying to automate in order to create a "minimal reproducible example"?